# which is effiecient in javascript, multidimensional array access or object access

Tags: javascript

I need to store stock market data for manipulation. Which is more efficient,

1) STORING DATA AS MULTIDIMENSION ARRAY FOR OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,date AS IN

```
//Data array stored in a array
var tickdata = new Array();
tickdata.push([open,high,low,close,volume,date])
```

2) storing data as an object object as shown below

```
function dailyData(open, high, low, close,volume,date)
{
   this.open = open;
   this.high = high;
   this.low = low;
   this.close = close;
   this.volume=volume;
   this.date=date;
}
var data = new Array();
data[0] = new dailyData(1017.50,1032.50 ,997.50, 1025.40,4187510,'07-Jan-2005');
```

Comment: Don't worry about this type of efficiency. It always varies between implementations anyway. Do whatever makes the most sense for the task at hand.

Comment: What does efficient mean for you? Efficient in space? Efficient in access time? Efficient in how fast you can code it?

Comment: @ Josiah Hester I mean efficiency here as access time.. I will do lot of access.. so will using as object will have some overhead..? If you say it depends on implementation.. I need efficient approach for chrome

Answer (score 1):

The second is easier to maintain in my opinion since you could edit setting values to change behavior.

The first option is harder to read, consider the following:

```
function sortData(data,index){
  data.sort(function(a,b){
   if(a[index]>b[index]){return 1;}
   if(a[index]<b[index]){return -1;}
   return 0;
  });
}
sortData(data,0);// sorts on open
```

where the second option might be easier to read:

```
function sortData(data,index){
  data.sort(function(a,b){
   if(a[index]>b[index]){return 1;}
   if(a[index]<b[index]){return -1;}
   return 0;
  });
}
sortData(data,"open");// sorts on open
```

Especially if you want to sort on multiple columns. Getting values is obviously easier to read: data[0][0] or data[0]["open"] or data[0].open

Formatting output cold easily be done with:

```
function dailyData(open, high, low, close,volume,date){
   //checking if data is valid comes here, maybe setting the
   // right type for the values (like date as date instead of string)
   this.open = open;
   this.high = high;
   this.low = low;
   this.close = close;
   this.volume=volume;
   this.date=date;
   this._dateYear={
      rerurn this.date.getFullYear();
   }
   this.dateYear=this._dateYear();
}
```

To (not) answer your question: I'm not sure if you would get performance loss using option 2 but I've used large arrays of objects and even on older browsers didn't have a problem with it.